# Android methods ordered within Activity

Tags: java, android, methods, android-activity

I have been searching for info about this issue but I didn´t find any convention or suggestion from Android documentation.

**Is there any Android convention about Activity´s lifecycle methods ordering?**

```
 public class Activity extends ApplicationContext {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

     protected void onStart();

     protected void onRestart();

     protected void onResume();

     protected void onPause();

     protected void onStop();

     protected void onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Completely opinionated: Anything but alphabetical order eventually drives me crazy. I don't *write* them in that order, but I'll periodically do an auto-format to fix it so I can find things.

Comment: I edited the question in order to fit the rules. I had added all my doubts to make the question clearer but I understand that it was causing opinion based answers. Right now the question is clear: Is there "official" Android conventions for this issue? Yes (link) or No. Hope the question now fits the rules because more people could have the same doubt and this post could be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no convention about ordering your methods in a file, you don't have to write your methods in the file following the order of execution, nor you have to implement a method before actually calling it in another one (you're not using old C/C++ compilers for example).

Just follow a logic ordering based on your needs and what you think is the best ordering if you have to modify the file weeks or months later.

I personally prefer, first to override framework methods and then all other methods I need in my Activity/Fragment/Service or whatever. But it's purely a matter of taste.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this [Activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

But as far as I know, there is no real convention for it, it is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

All of these classes here:

```
public class Activity extends ApplicationContext {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);

     protected void onStart();

     protected void onRestart();

     protected void onResume();

     protected void onPause();

     protected void onStop();

     protected void onDestroy();
 }
```

are methods that either need to be defined, or can be overridden. They are native to the SDK. They are executed in the order you have, however, if you are going to override them, you don't need to place them in particular order. They are the methods of the Activity lifecycle, so they will automatically be executed in the order they need to be.